# iOS 8.3, Keyboard Extenstion Safari issue

Tags: ios, safari, grand-central-dispatch, ios-keyboard-extension, ios8.3

I'm making the iOS keyboard extension.

But When I do following code after button click in Safari Web, the proxy(`UITextDocumentProxy`) stopped.

```
[self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:-5];//stop here
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"__________"];
```

It works well in safari-top-search-bar, but stop at other plain textbox.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.online",0);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    [self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:-5];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
    }
    [self.textDocumentProxy insertText:@"__________"];
});
```

If I put the block into dispatch_async on another queue with some delay after *adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset*. **It_works**

However it makes my code slow in whole other apps also.

Any good idea? or Is there any way to detect whether it is Safari or Not?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem. It seems that if you do `insertText` or `adjustTextPosition`, you can't immediately call `deleteBackward` or `adjustTextPosition`. Our current workaround is to use NSTimer to delay for some time:

```
[self.textDocumentProxy adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset:-5];
[self delayedDelete];
```

While `delayedDelete` could be like:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(deleteBackward) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

I'm thinking it's a bug of iOS and not documented yet.

Comment: I tried wrapping each method(such as deleteBackword, adjust...)  with gcd for running after some delay, but it looks like unintended animation...